# Creating custom std::streambuf

Tags: c++, file-io, stl

I am defining a custom `std::streambuf` class for use in file I/O. In this class, I am overloading the functions `open`, `close`, `is_open`, `xsgetn`, `xsputn`, `overflow`, `underflow`, and `uflow`. I then insert this buffer into an `std::ifstream` as follows (the same scenario holds for `std::ofstream`):

```
std::ifstream temp;
Filebuffer *buffer = new Filebuffer();
buffer->open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
temp.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(buffer);
```

The implementation for `Filebuffer` (my custom class) is as follows:

```
std::streamsize
Filebuffer::xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n)
{
  std::streamsize result = 0;

  if(file && n)
  {
    for(;;)
    {
      size_t buffer_use = this->epptr() - this->pptr();

      if(buffer_use > 0)
      {
        if(static_cast<int>(buffer_use) > n)
        {
          buffer_use = n;
        }

        std::char_traits<char>::copy(this->pptr(), s, buffer_use);

        this->pbump(buffer_use);
        result += buffer_use;
        n -= buffer_use;

        if(n == 0)
        {
          break;
        }

        s += buffer_use;
      }

      this->overflow(static_cast<int>(*s));
    }
  }

  return result;
}

std::streamsize
Filebuffer::xsgetn(char *s, std::streamsize n)
{
  std::streamsize result = 0;

  if(file && n)
  {
    int ch;    do
    {
      size_t buffer_use = this->egptr() - this->gptr();

      if(buffer_use > 0)
      {
        if(static_cast<int>(buffer_use) > n)
        {
          buffer_use = n;
        }

        std::char_traits<char>::copy(s, this->gptr(), buffer_use);

        this->gbump(buffer_use);
        result += buffer_use;
        n -= buffer_use;

        if(n == 0)
        {
          break;
        }

        s += buffer_use;
      }

      ch = this->underflow();
    } while(!(ch == std::char_traits<char>::eof()));
  }

  return result;
}

int
Filebuffer::underflow()
{
  if(file)
  {
    nullify_put_area(); //clears write buffer

    if(!buffer) //allocated in open()
    {
      int value = ungetc(fgetc(file), file);

      if(value == EOF)
      {
        return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
      }

      return value;
    }

    char *begin = buffer;
    char *end = buffer + bufferSize - 1; //bufferSize set to 4 KB
    char *next = end;

    if(this->gptr() < this->egptr())
    {
      size_t buffer_use = this->egptr() - this->gptr();

      memmove(begin, next, buffer_use);
      begin += buffer_use;
    }

    setg(begin, begin, begin);


    size_t m = (bufferSize - 1 - (begin - this->eback()));

    if(m > 0)
    {
      size_t status = fread(begin, 1, m, file);

      if(status == 0)
      {
        return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
      }

      setg(this->eback(), this->gptr(), begin + status);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(*this->gptr());
  }

  return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
}

int
Filebuffer::uflow()
{
  if(!file)
  {
    return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
  }

  int ch = underflow();

  if(ch != std::char_traits<char>::eof())
  {
    if(buffer)
    {
      this->gbump(1);
    }

    else
    {
      fgetc(file);
    }
  }

  return ch;
}

int
Filebuffer::overflow(int c)
{
  if(!file)
  {
    return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
  }

  const char *begin = this->pbase();
  char *next = this->pptr();

  if(buffer)
  {
    setp(buffer, buffer + bufferSize - 1);
  }

  nullify_get_area(); //clears read buffer

  char temp;
  if(c == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
  {
    c = std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(std::char_traits<char>::eof());
  }

  else
  {
    if(!next)
    {
      begin = next = &temp;
    }

    assert(next == &temp || buffer <= next);
    assert(next == &temp || next < buffer + bufferSize);
    *next++ = static_cast<char>(c);
  }

  if(begin != next)
  {
    if(begin == &temp)
    {
      fputc(temp, file);
      return c;
    }

    size_t n = next - begin;
    size_t status = fwrite(begin, 1, n, file);

    if(status != n)
    {
      return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
    }

    return c;
  }

  return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
}
```

Unfortunately, whenever I use (e.g.) `temp >> readVar;`, it does not use any of my overloaded functions - the call stack shows that the STL original implementations were called - and instead, simply reads in garbage. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295693/intercept-all-writes-to-a-stdstreambuf), I need to define `overflow` for `ofstream` (and presumably, `underflow` for `ifstream`), which I have done. Am I defining `xsputn` and `xsgetn` correctly? Why are my overloaded functions not being called?

Comment: `basic_ifstream` has it's own internal `basic_filebuf`, which may be separate from the `basic_streambuf` that you're setting via `basic_ios`. I'm not sure that you can change it.

Comment: Why are you putting this into an `std::fstream`? You can take a plain `std::iostream` instead. Also, IOStreams have never been part of the STL, the two only met when both were being integrated into the C++ standard library. That said, explicitly calling `basic_ios<char>::rdbuf` seems both weird and unnecessary, but maybe that's a side-effect of using an `std::fstream` in the first place.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Primarily because I'm modifying an existing code base and changing all instances of `std::fstream` to `std::iostream` is a pain in the rear end that I would like to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: `std::fstream` defines its own `rdbuf()` method which hides `rdbuf(streambuf *)`, so I need to explicitly call `basic_ios<char>`, or it won't work.

Comment: The question that's still unclear is whether your streambuffer work correctly when used in combination with a plain `std::iostream`? Also, you should consider providing a minimal example. In any case, try to get hold of Langer and Kreft's "C++ IOStreams and Locales", that book invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that trying to do this with `std::ifstream` will not work, and I need to change it `std::istream`. Once I make this change, the overloaded functions are called and everything works properly.